# How NodeJS app access resources from a disabled CORS(Cross Origin Sharing) Server using HTTP requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cors

I am aware that there's a need in server side to enable CORS so as clients can access server resources programmatically. Otherwise the client request will result to `blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`

I was trying to make a Scraper in client side using 2 ways, First is jQuery and NodeJS App(using Request Library). Note: the website that I am going to access has DISABLED their CORS.

When I tested it the responses are:

jQuery -> `blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`

NodeJS App -> `Status OK 200 and I was able to scrape.`

How NodeJS app access resources from a disabled CORS(Cross Origin Sharing) Server using HTTP requests?

I am wondering is it because of V8 engine act as a browser when NodeJS send request?

Comment: Because node.js is not a web browser. Learn the difference.

Comment: Says CORS is disabled... gets CORS rejection... OP what you smoking?

Answer (score 3):

CORS is just an agreement that browsers follow. It doesn't apply to back-end servers like your nodejs app.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS